# query data in a airtable database using url

Tags: database, postman, airtable

I want to implement URL for search specific data in my base using `filterByFormula` 
below are my link and I got an error and how to resolve that

my url:

```
api.airtable.com/v0/APPID/Stories?filterByFormula=(FIND(“Car (in robot form) will offer a hug when I am stressed out”,{User want}) &api_key=MYKEY


Error : 
{
    "error": {
        "type": "INVALID_FILTER_BY_FORMULA",
        "message": "The formula for filtering records is invalid: Invalid formula. Please check your formula text."
    }
}
```

I tried using postman, please help me.

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis.  Either remove the one before `FIND` or add one after `{User want})`.  You can generally check a formula's validity by creating a new formula field in your Airtable base and putting the formula there.  If it works in the base, it should work in the API.

Answer (score 0):

While querying filtered data from Airtable via API, you don't have to use `FIND` keyword. You can filter data with simple Airtable formula like structure. For example,

```
{Email} = 'johnwick@neverdie.com'
```

Above filter retrieve all the records from the table whose `Email` is simply `johnwick@neverdie.com`

To limit number of records retrieve by API `maxRecord` parameter is available for that. For more info about various parameters please refer my answer here [AirTable API Find record by email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825822/airtable-api-find-record-by-email/60986706#60986706) or official Airtable API Documentation

**In your case**

API url would be structured like,

```
api.airtable.com/v0/APPID/Stories?filterByFormula=Car+(in+robot+form)+will+offer+a+hug+when+I+am+stressed+out%3D%22User+want%22&api_key=MYKEY
```

For more info about Airtable API encoding, check this https://codepen.io/airtable/full/rLKkYB?baseId=app1C5TVoophmmr8M&tableId=tblvILr4aSAYI98oa

Hope this helps!